# Ants Profiler: How to optimize time spend in "Assembly load or unload"

Tags: .net, asp.net, reflection, profiler, ants

I am using Ants Profiler to profile my ASP.Net application. The profiler shows the system spend nearly 30% time in "Assembly load or unload" and there was a hit count of 65. Any ideas on how can I optimize the "Assembly load or unload" time?? 
My ASP.Net application consists of nearly 10 project\dll references. The asp.net application also caches frequently used data into xml files and reading the cached data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading assemblies *is* an expensive operation, however once an assembly is loaded, it cannot be unloaded unless the entire app domain is unloaded.  Profiling is all relative.  If you are profiling the application startup, then yes, assembly loading will show up as a major bottleneck, but over a longer time period, the relative percentage of time spent loading assemblies should be much lower.